# How to get the value of Person field and Lookup field depending on ItemID using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, person, copy-item

I have a form where I have a lookup field displaying issue ids of same list. On selection of Issue id, Person field (Issue Assigned to) and other Lookup field (Function) to be prefilled. I have achieved this for other type of fields.

How to get values of Person and lookup columns?

Answer (score 0):

Values for the Person/Group field are controlled by the user id from UPS.  Display name will not work.  Use the user ID and you will be able to prepopulate your user field.

Comment: How? can you show some example

Answer (score 0):

**For Lookup Field,**

- To Get the selected Lookup value in the current form

  ```
  LItem.get_item("Internal Name of Lookup field").get_lookupValue();
  ```
- To Set the selected lookup value to another Lookup field in the current form

  ```
  $("select[title='Lookup field Name']").val(LItem.get_item("Internal Name of Lookup field").get_lookupValue());
  ```

**For People Field,**

To Get the People Field value

```
Item.get_item("Intrnal Name of People field").get_lookupValue();
```

To Set it to a People field value in the current form

```
 var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = context.get_web();
 var user = web.ensureUser(LItem.get_item("Intrnal Name of People field").get_lookupValue());
 context.load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){ 
var form = $("table[class='ms-formtable']"); 
var userField = form.find("input[id$='ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput']").get(0);
var peoplepicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.PickerObjectFromSubElement(userField);
var loginName = user.get_loginName();
peoplepicker.AddUserKeys(loginName);},function(sender,args){ // on error
 alert(args.get_message());});
```

For more details check [Auto-Populate the Lookup and People Fields in List form  based on lookup selection in sharepoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/01/10/autofill-list-form-fields-based-on-lookup-selection-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Its getting the correct value for Lookup field but not setting the. It just sets it blank (from default value "(None)"

Comment: For lookup field this worked : var check = ListItem.get_item("Functionn").get_lookupValue();
var allOptions = document.querySelectorAll("[title=Functionn] option");

[].some.call(allOptions, function(option) {
    if (option.innerHTML == check) {
        option.selected = "selected";
        return true;
    }
});

Comment: Have you checked the attached link! it set the lookup value if it already there?!

Comment: For People field its giving an error - "SPClientPeoplePicker is not defined". Can you help?

Comment: Yes, I tried the code from your link itself. Full code that you have given